# Create Summary Report Combining All Jtl files

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am using following plugins to create html files of all the jmeter

1.jmeter-maven-plugin
2.xml-maven-plugin

With the use of above plugins, Html reports are getting created of individual jmeter but now I want to create summary html reports which contains the summary of All Jmeter Html reports

Is there any ready made maven plugin for doing this or I will have to create new plugin which will create one Summary Report

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your test plan structure it's hard so come up with the best suggestion, if you want to combine multiple results into a single .jtl file you can take a look at [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) - it can merge up to 4 .jtl results files into a single one. If you have > 4 - you will have to execute the tool more than once.

You can install Merge Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) for standalone JMeter instalaltion.

[image]

In case of JMeter Maven Plugin you can add the plugin to JMeter via [`<jmeterExtensions>` tag:](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-mergeresults:2.1</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
    <!-- The plugin uses some broken dependencies
         An alternative is to set this to true and use excludedArtifacts, see below
    -->
    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
</configuration>
```